# How to plot both x and y error bars?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

It used to be possible to plot both horizontal and vertical error bars ErrorlistPlot and ErrorBars.  However, this has been removed since version 12.  It seems that Around only allows vertical error bars.  Is there any simpler way to do this without manually constructing a Graphic with a horizontal line and end caps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *Mathematica* v 12.0 and above, just use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)both for the $x$ and $y$ values in the data and plot with [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
{
  {Around[0.7, {0.5, 0.9}], Around[0.4, {0.5, 0.9}]},
  {Around[0.9, {0.6, 0.9}], Around[0.3, {0.6, 0.9}]},
  {Around[0.7, {1.0, 0.5}], Around[0.7, {1.0, 0.5}]},
  {Around[0.6, {0.6, 0.3}], Around[0.5, {0.6, 0.3}]}
}

ListPlot[
    Around@@@RandomReal[1,{10,2,2}]
    ,PlotTheme->"Scientific"
]
```

[image]